# Getting Multiple Ips in Admin order "Placed from IP"

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, sales-order, ip-address

From few days i am getting multiple IP addresses in Admin Order Page.

It looks like

```
Placed from IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

& Seems IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy is correct one.

Anyone please can tell why this started happening.

Got the same question here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033732/multiple-placed-from-ip-addresses-in-magento

But answer is not useful.

Comment: is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx a local ip like 192.xxx or 172.xxx or 10.xx ?

Comment: No this is some ip from Singapore location 52.77.XXX. For all orders its coming same.

Answer (score 3):

The IP addresses in the brackets come from the X_FORWARDED_FOR header of the request. If you had a reverse proxy such as Varnish set-up on your server, this may be configured to copy the customers IP into the X_FORWARDED_FOR header and the REMOTE_ADDR header would be the IP address of the reverse proxy server. If this is happening for all orders then a change in your servers infrastructure to do this is the most likely cause.

If it's not happening for everyone then it's most likely people accessing your site through some kind of proxy service (people may be doing this to get around country filters etc, though a true privacy proxy wouldn't populate the X_FORWARDED FOR HEADER) that is adding the header into the request on the customers behalf. Since this is just a header from the request anybody accessing your site can theoretically send any value they like for this header.